# C++ Video Playing + Alphas and Other Questions

Tags: c++, video

I am making a simple game for fun and learning using SFML for 2D stuff. The game is rather simple.. I loath to say it is a HoG (hidden object game) but I guess that would be a way to get my point across quickly. Basically I am using SFML to load and display 2D still art and capture mouse events.

Anyway... I would like to add video clips to my project. All the art is rendered and for example.. if my image is of a park with a fountain, I would like to have a looping video of the water running so the image has some life even though it is just a still.

All I need is the ability to play videos in the window, preferably compatible with sfml but I am in the planning projects I can swap to something else if needed. The project will have a set resolution (not scalable) and I just want to load the video and play them at a certain pixel location in x,y. So if I have a 1200x720 image I play a 100x100 pixel video on loop at a certain location to make the water of the fountain move.

Now then I am thinking I can just load 2D sprites onto of the video matching the background image to do simple masking. There are some formats like quicktime that can embed an alpha channel directly into the video and if that is supported awesome.. but some planning in the set design should mean that is not really needed. Though if that was supported more options open in set design.

I am pretty good with video as I am a 3D animator by profession, new to programming as a learning hobby. So the format and container of the video is not really an issue though I have been working with OGV a lot recently.

What I see as it needing is

Load multiple videos at once
Play with out any boarders or anything
Play at specific locations in a window.
loop seamlessly
Allow zdepth so I can place sprites onto of it

Dose anyone know were I would go to start looking into this? It seams like something that could possibly be a library I could use? Preferably an open source one as this is just a for fun project nothing commercial.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have.